# Calculating offset when crossing a river with speed profile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

I am having some issues putting the theory I learned into practise.
We have an exercise, that goes as following:

A swimmer wants to cross a river with width b. The swimmer heads straight to the other side of the river ($\alpha = 0$, his speed is orthogonal to the coast). The speed of the swimmer is constant.

The rivers speed profile is given by:

$$v_p(y) = cy(b-y)$$

where

$$c= 1.2\cdot 10^{-3} \ (\mathrm{m\cdot s})^{-1}$$

Now I need to calculate the distance s the simmer travelled in $x$ direction when reaching the other side of the coast.

This is what I came up with so far:

In order to calculate the distance $s$, I need to integrate $v_p(y)$ to get a distance. This gives me $s(t) = cy(b-y)t$. Now I need to take the integral from $0$ to $b$.
This is where it gets tricky. I tried to get the integral but I always end up getting something with the unit $\mathrm{m}^2$ which obviously can not be.

How do I calculate the distance s correctly?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: In your equation for the velocity the right hand side has dimension $m^{3}s^{-1}$. I suspect it should be more like $c\frac{y}{b}\left(1-\frac{y}{b}\right)$ which has the dimenions of velocity.

Comment: Actually it gives m/s^-1. [y] = m, [b]= m. Therefor [c] * m^2 = m/s^(-1)

Comment: I am not sure but I think I figured it out :) :
if I set y(t) = v*t then I get vp(t) = c*v*t*(b-v*t). With the integral vp(t) dt from 0 to s/v I then get c * b^2/b *b / 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think i figured this out by myself:

If you set 
$$y(t) = v_y * t $$

then you get

$$v_p(t) = c* v_y*t*(b-v*t) $$

after that we can now take the integral:
$$ s_x = \int_{0}^{s/v} v_p(t) dt = -c *s_y^2/v * (2s_y-3b) / 6$$

with $s_y = b$ we get

$$ c*b^2/v*b/6 = 0.2*10^{-3}*b^3/v $$